# Question hyperlinks have a different font size than answer hyperlinks in the 10k mod tools page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [10k /tools page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools), question links have a larger font-size than answer links:

[image: 10k tools page screenshot]

They have different colors as well, but I'm not certain if that is by-design or not.

Any link with class `question-hyperlink` is 18px; links with class `answer-hyperlink` have their font-size set to 100% (13px).

Comment: Show off. Not many others ever see that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with the April 2015 [updates to the site](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/8708).