# Flags summary page styling

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Right now our flag summary pages ([this is mine](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/23061)) look something like this:

[image: my flag page with issue highlighted]

There's a good amount of misalignment going on, from the vote count with the question title, to the flag reason and vote count, to the user info part of the right side.

The question and answer font sizes are different from each other, answers are 15px and questions are 18px (this could be related to [this meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/929/23061)).

There also seems to be some white space missing between `duplicate of` and the question name (or the font size could be made the same).

#### Could we get this page cleaned up a bit, style wise?

Here's what StackOverflow's looks like (a lot better IMO even though the user info part is not aligned) for reference:

[image: an example of the SO flag summary page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design team is currently working on converting all of its CSS to some other, newer, fresher, hipper cousin. (I'll let them divulge details.) They tell me that when the conversion is complete on GD SE it will eliminate this bug.

Comment: This was fixed with the April 2015 [updates to the site](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/updates-to-the-site)